# MySQL average numbers of items delivered per hour per day per month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average, hour

I am using `MySQL`,
I would like to fetch average numbers of items delivered per hour per day

For example:

for January we had 5 Mondays,
January 2 - 2 items
January 9 - 0
January 16 - 0
January 23 - 1
January 30 - 0 items delivered

Average = (2+0+0+1+0)/5 = 0.6 items delivered during the 1:00-2:00 hour time period for Monday

[Output what I am getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHUke.jpg)

**I used the below coding:**

```
SELECT 
    Hour(CST_data.dateandtime_CST) as Hours_Order,  
    Concat(Hour(CST_data.dateandtime_CST), ':00-', Hour(CST_data.dateandtime_CST) + 1, ':00') as Hours_in_CST,  
    Sum(DayofWeek(CST_data.dateandtime_CST)=1) as Sun,  
    Sum(DayofWeek(CST_data.dateandtime_CST)=2) as Mon,  
    Sum(DayofWeek(CST_data.dateandtime_CST)=3) as Tue,  
    Sum(DayofWeek(CST_data.dateandtime_CST)=4) as Wed,  
    Sum(DayofWeek(CST_data.dateandtime_CST)=5) as Thu,  
    Sum(DayofWeek(CST_data.dateandtime_CST)=6) as Fri,  
    Sum(DayofWeek(CST_data.dateandtime_CST)=7) as Sat,  
    Count(CST_data.dateandtime_CST) as Total_Count,  
    count(distinct(day(CST_data.dateandtime_CST))) as No_of_Days,  
    Count(CST_data.dateandtime_CST) / count( distinct(day(CST_data.dateandtime_CST))) as Avg_Count   
FROM  
    (Select Timestampadd(Hour,-5,updated_at) as dateandtime_CST from  
    case_state_transitions  
where  
    To_state = 'delivered'  
        and date(dateandtime) between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'  
        ) as CST_data  
group by Hours_in_CST, Hours_Order  
order by Hours_Order;
```

**Can you please help me finding number of Mondays (Sunday to Saturday) available in this coding itself.**

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am new to MySql. Please help me...

Comment: export your 'case_state_transitions' table with data and open file and copy code and paste in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1. so it's easy to solve by anyone